# Dynamic programming exercise for string cutting

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have been working on the following problem from this [book](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms/chap6.pdf).

> A certain string-processing language offers a primitive operation which splits a string into two pieces. Since this operation involves copying the original string, it takes n units of time for a string of length n, regardless of the location of the cut. Suppose, now, that you want to break a string into many pieces. The order in which the breaks are made can affect the total running time. For example, if you want to cut a 20-character string at positions 3 and 10, then making the first cut at position 3 incurs a total cost of 20+17=37, while doing position 10 first has a better cost of 20+10=30.

I need a dynamic programming algorithm that given m cuts, finds the minimum cost of cutting a string into m+1 pieces.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation of cutting cost of the string. Can you tell me how did you get `20+17` and `20+10`?

Comment: a yet more optimal solution would involve having a dynamic algorithm running a constant time of n regardless of m, which would be even more efficient. Just a thought.

Comment: @noMAD: for 20+17, 20 is from cost of cutting length 3 while 17 is from cost of cutting length 20-3 = 17.

Comment: @Mark: That raises one more question. Is the second or subsequent cutting relative to the previous cutting? Example, if its `3 and 10` the first `3rd` position is cut and then 17 remains and then `10th` position is cut (but with respect to original word `13th` is cut)??

Comment: @noMAD: The cutting positions are fixed.

Comment: Sidenote: is there another (named) problem that is equivalent to this, and whose solution could be applied here? I'm sure there is, I just can't think of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The divide and conquer approach seems to me the best one for this kind of problem. Here is a Java implementation of the algorithm:

**Note**: the array `m` should be sorted in ascending order (use `Arrays.sort(m);`)

```
public int findMinCutCost(int[] m, int n) {
   int cost = n * m.length;
   for (int i=0; i<m.length; i++) {
      cost = Math.min(findMinCutCostImpl(m, n, i), cost);
   }
   return cost;
}

private int findMinCutCostImpl(int[] m, int n, int i) {
   if (m.length == 1) return n;
   int cl = 0, cr = 0;
   if (i > 0) {
      cl = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      int[] ml = Arrays.copyOfRange(m, 0, i);
      int nl = m[i];
      for (int j=0; j<ml.length; j++) {
         cl = Math.min(findMinCutCostImpl(ml, nl, j), cl);
      }
   }
   if (i < m.length - 1) {
      cr = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      int[] mr = Arrays.copyOfRange(m, i + 1, m.length);
      int nr = n - m[i];
      for (int j=0; j<mr.length; j++) {
         mr[j] = mr[j] - m[i];
      }
      for (int j=0; j<mr.length; j++) {
         cr = Math.min(findMinCutCostImpl(mr, nr, j), cr);
      }
   }
   return n + cl + cr;
}
```

For example :

```
 int n = 20;
 int[] m = new int[] { 10, 3 };

 System.out.println(findMinCutCost(m, n));
```

Will print `30`

** **Edit** **

I have implemented two other methods to answer the problem in the question.

#### 1. Median cut approximation

This method cut recursively always the biggest chunks. The results are not always the best solution, but offers a not negligible gain (in the order of +100000% gain from my tests) for a negligible minimal cut loss difference from the best cost.

```
public int findMinCutCost2(int[] m, int n) {
   if (m.length == 0) return 0;
   if (m.length == 1) return n;
      float half = n/2f;
      int bestIndex = 0;
      for (int i=1; i<m.length; i++) {
         if (Math.abs(half - m[bestIndex]) > Math.abs(half - m[i])) {
            bestIndex = i;
         }
      }
      int cl = 0, cr = 0;
      if (bestIndex > 0) {
         int[] ml = Arrays.copyOfRange(m, 0, bestIndex);
         int nl = m[bestIndex];
         cl = findMinCutCost2(ml, nl);
      }
      if (bestIndex < m.length - 1) {
         int[] mr = Arrays.copyOfRange(m, bestIndex + 1, m.length);
         int nr = n - m[bestIndex];
         for (int j=0; j<mr.length; j++) {
         mr[j] = mr[j] - m[bestIndex];
      }
      cr = findMinCutCost2(mr, nr);
   }
   return n + cl + cr;
}
```

#### 2. A constant time multi-cut

Instead of *calculating* the minimal cost, just use different indices and buffers. Since this method executes in a constant time, it always returns n. Plus, the method *actually* split the string in substrings.

```
public int findMinCutCost3(int[] m, int n) {
   char[][] charArr = new char[m.length+1][];
   charArr[0] = new char[m[0]];
   for (int i=0, j=0, k=0; j<n; j++) {
      //charArr[i][k++] = string[j];   // string is the actual string to split
      if (i < m.length && j == m[i]) {
         if (++i >= m.length) {
            charArr[i] = new char[n - m[i-1]];
         } else {
            charArr[i] = new char[m[i] - m[i-1]];
         }
         k=0;
      }
   }
   return n;
}
```

**Note**: that this last method could easily be modified to accept a `String str` argument instead of `n` and set `n = str.length()`, and return a `String[]` array from `charArr[][]`.

Comment: could we not just sort the array of cuts and take the array from right to left and get the the best cut algorithm from that? It seems the best cuts go from the highest cut to the lowest cut in sorted order. just curious.

Comment: Woa! This is an old one! It seems I got wiser since then :) If the OP doesn't mind, I can completely rewrite this with a better explanation and code, because... WTF was I thinking when I wrote `findMinCutCost2` ?? LOL

Answer (score 3):

For dynamic programming, I claim that all you really need to know is what the state space should be - how to represent partial problems.

Here we are dividing a string up into m+1 pieces by creating new breaks. I claim that a good state space is a set of (a, b) pairs, where a is the location of the start of a substring and b is the location of the end of the same substring, counted as number of breaks in the final broken down string. The cost associated with each pair is the minimum cost of breaking it up. If b <= a + 1, then the cost is 0, because there are no more breaks to put in. If b is larger, then the possible locations for the next break in that substring are the points a+1, a+2,... b-1. The next break is going to cost b-a regardless of where we put it, but if we put it at position k the minimum cost of later breaks is (a, k) + (k, b).

So to solve this with dynamic programming, build up a table (a, b) of minimum costs, where you can work out the cost of breaks on strings with k sections by considering k - 1 possible breaks and then looking up the costs of strings with at most k - 1 sections.

One way to expand on this would be to start by creating a table T[a, b] and setting all entries in that table to infinity. Then go over the table again and where b <= a+1 put T[a,b] = 0. This fills in entries representing sections of the original string which need no further cuts. Now scan through the table and for each T[a,b] with b > a + 1 consider every possible k such that a < k < b and if min_k ((length between breaks a and b) + T[a,k] + T[k,b]) < T[a,b] set T[a,b] to that minimum value. This recognizes where you now know a way to chop up the substrings represented by T[a,k] and T[k,b] cheaply, so this gives you a better way to chop up T[a,b]. If you now repeat this m times you are done - use a standard dynamic programming backtrack to work out the solution. It might help if you save the best value of k for each T[a,b] in a separate table.

Comment: Can you help me with this explanation by expanding on your last paragraph? That is I'm not sure what you mean by a table (a,b) of minimum costs  and working out the cost of breaks. Basically, I don't understand much of anything with the last paragraph.

Comment: I have expanded this as requested. The thing to remember is that T[a,b] holds the best cost seen so far of chopping up a section of the string between a and b, where a and b are measured in terms of the number of breaks to be made, not the number of characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to get a solution and am now able to figure your last paragraph and understand the solution. My problem now is getting that break sequence out of the min costs. For example with a break array of {2, 8, 10} we get the best min cost of 38 and a break sequence of 10, 8, 2 or 10, 2, 8. Getting that last array or break sequence is giving me a hard time.

Comment: I wanted to ask one more question to make sure I have understood it correctly. Here is how I solve it.

I have a character cut string of (2,8,10). I can bookmark 0, 20 to this string to work through my algorithm easier. Thus I now have 0, 2, 8, 10, 20. My primitive values are (0,2), (2, 8) and so on. So those values are all minimum 0. The next level has the cut (0,8). The minimum best cut there is 8-0 + 0 is 8. I can solve (2,10) the same and get 8. I can then solve (0,10) and get 10-0 + 8 for 18 and so on. 

Getting the best cut sequence array out of that one could go backwards.

Comment: That sounds plausible but it has been a long time since I worked on this question so it is possible that I have missed a detail.

Answer (score 2):

python code:

```
mincost(n, cut_list) =min {   n+ mincost(k,left_cut_list) + min(n-k, right_cut_list) }


import sys

def splitstr(n,cut_list):

        if len(cut_list) == 0: 
            return [0,[]]
        min_positions = []
        min_cost = sys.maxint
        for k in cut_list:
            left_split = [ x for x in cut_list if x < k]
            right_split = [ x-k for x in cut_list if x > k] 
            #print n,k, left_split, right_split
            lcost = splitstr(k,left_split)
            rcost = splitstr(n-k,right_split)      
            cost = n+lcost[0] + rcost[0]
            positions = [k] + lcost[1]+ [x+k for x in rcost[1]] 
            #print "cost:", cost, " min: ", positions
            if cost < min_cost:
                min_cost = cost
                min_positions = positions

        return ( min_cost, min_positions) 



print splitstr(20,[3,10,16])  # (40, [10, 3, 16])

print splitstr(20,[3,10]) # (30, [10, 3])

print splitstr(5,[1,2,3,4,5]) # (13, [2, 1, 3, 4, 5])

print splitstr(1,[1]) # (1, [1]) # m cuts m+1 substrings
```

Comment: A little bit of explanation would make your answer more valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a c++ implementation. Its an O(n^3) Implementation using D.P . Assuming that the cut array is sorted . If it is not it takes O(n^3) time to sort it hence asymptotic time complexity remains same.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int i,j,gap,k,l,m,n;
    while(scanf("%d%d",&n,&k)!=EOF){

        int a[n+1][n+1];
        int cut[k];
        memset(a,0,sizeof(a));
        for(i=0;i<k;i++)
            cin >> cut[i];
        for(gap=1;gap<=n;gap++){
            for(i=0,j=i+gap;j<=n;j++,i++){
                if(gap==1)
                    a[i][j]=0;
                else{
                    int min = INT_MAX;
                    for(m=0;m<k;m++){
                        if(cut[m]<j and cut[m] >i){
                            int cost=(j-i)+a[i][cut[m]]+a[cut[m]][j];

                            if(cost<min)
                                min=cost;
                        }
                    }
                    if(min>=INT_MAX)
                    a[i][j]=0;
                    else
                        a[i][j]=min;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << a[0][n] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```