# dynamic programming for minimum cost of breaking the string

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

> A certain string-processing language offers a primitive operation which splits a string into two pieces. Since this operation involves copying the original string, it takes n units of time for a string of length n, regardless of the location of the cut. Suppose, now, that you want to break a string into many pieces. The order in which the breaks are made can affect the total running time. For example, if you want to cut a 20-character string at positions 3 and 10, then making the first cut at position 3 incurs a total cost of 20+17=37, while doing position 10 first has a better cost of 20+10=30.
>
> Give a dynamic programming algorithm that, given the locations of m cuts in a string of length n, finds the minimum cost of breaking the string into m + 1 pieces.

This problem is from "Algorithms" chapter6 6.9.

Since there is no answer for this problem, This is what I thought.

Define `OPT(i,j,n)` as the minimum cost of breaking the string, `i` for start index, `j` for end index of String and `n` for the remaining number of cut I can use.

Here is what I get:

`OPT(i,j,n) = min {OPT(i,k,w) + OPT(k+1,j,n-w) + j-i} for i<=k<j and 0<=w<=n`

Is it right or not? Please help, thx!

Comment: Implement and test it?

Comment: Hint: Do you need the `n` parameter?  :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker This thing has really troubled me for several days..I cannot figure out why not need the n parameter.. If you know the answer, pleeeease tell me, thx!

Comment: Suppose we have the string fragment consisting of block i through block j, inclusive.  We want to compute OPT(i, j) -- the lowest-cost way to split this fragment into all its j-i+1 subfragments.  We can make our first cut in one of j-i places.  Suppose we cut it into 2 sub-fragments, consisting of blocks i through k inclusive, and blocks k+1 through j inclusive.  If we know (a) the lowest-cost way to cut fragment (i, k) and (b) the lowest-cost way to cut fragment (k+1, j), then we can figure out OPT(i, j), right?  Now what are (a) and (b)?

Comment: @j_random_hacker I still do not understand.. if you do not use `n` parameter, how can you guarantee that the number of cut is exactly `m` cuts

Comment: You have to have a "base case": When i = j, OPT(i, j) = 0.  That's because you have already have a final block that needs no further subdivision.  Actually I just realised I misinterpreted something you wrote... I'll write another comment in a second.

Comment: I see why my explanation was confusing for you!  Instead of using i and j to be indices (positions) in the string, consider them to be *block numbers*.  There are m+1 blocks in the string, defined by the m cuts that you need to make.  E.g. in the example, there are 3 blocks: 1-3, 4-10 and 11-20 (assuming "cut at position 3" means "cut after position 3").

Comment: @j-random-hacker So what you mean is that the index i and j I point here should be the index of block instead of index of string?

Comment: Yes!  BTW I wasn't notified of this comment because my username has underscores, not hyphens.

Comment: @j_random_hacker One more question. If I use index `i` and `j` to be the index of block, I cannot write the cost like I previously did(i.e. `j-i`). How should I do then?

Comment: Hint: it involves having an array of the end positions (or start positions) of each block.

Comment: Your question has been asked (and answered!) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068568/dynamic-programming-exercise-for-string-cutting?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic programming exercise for string cutting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068568/dynamic-programming-exercise-for-string-cutting)

Answer (score 3):

I think your recurrence relation can become more better. Here's what I came up with, define cost(i,j) to be the cost of cutting the string from index i to j. Then,

```
cost(i,j) = min {length of substring + cost(i,k) + cost(k,j) where i < k < j}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 void  s_cut()    
  {
    int l,p;
    int temp=0;
    //ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int al[];
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    int table[][];
    ArrayList<Integer> values[][];
    int low=0,high=0;
    int min=0;

    l=s.nextInt();
    p=s.nextInt();

    System.out.println("The values are "+l+"  "+p);

    table= new int[l+1][l+1];
    values= new ArrayList[l+1][l+1];
    al= new int[p];

    for(int i=0;i<p;i++)
    {
        al[i]=s.nextInt();

    }

    for(int i=0;i<=l;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<=l;j++)
        values[i][j]=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    System.out.println();

    for(int i=1;i<=l;i++)
        table[i][i]=0;
    //Arrays.s
    Arrays.sort(al);

    for(int i=0;i<p;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(al[i]+ "  ");

    }


    for(int len=2;len<=l;len++)
    {
        //System.out.println("The length is  "+len);

        for(int i=1,j=i+len-1;j<=l;i++,j++)
        {

            high= min_index(al,j-1);
            low= max_index(al,i);

            System.out.println("Indices are "+low+"  "+high);

            if(low<=high && low!=-1 && high!=-1)
            {

            int cost=Integer.MAX_VALUE;;

            for(int k=low;k<=high;k++)
            {
                //if(al[k]!=j)
                temp=cost;
                cost=Math.min(cost, table[i][al[k]]+table[al[k]+1][j]);

                if(temp!=cost)
                {
                    min=k; 
                    //values[i][j].add(al[k]);
                    //values[i][j].addAll(values[i][al[k]]);
                    //values[i][j].addAll(values[al[k]+1][j]);
                    //values[i][j].addAll(values[i][al[k]]);
                }

                //else
                //cost=0;
            }

            table[i][j]= len+cost;

            values[i][j].add(al[min]);
            //values[i][j].addAll(values[i][al[min]]);
            values[i][j].addAll(values[al[min]+1][j]);
            values[i][j].addAll(values[i][al[min]]);

            }

            else
                table[i][j]=0;

            System.out.println(" values are "+i+"  "+j+"  "+table[i][j]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(" The minimum cost is "+table[1][l]);

    //temp=values[1][l];
    for(int e: values[1][l])
    {
        System.out.print(e+"-->");

    }

}
```

The above solution has the complexity of O(n^3).